# Access a key outside of an array and store in a variable

Tags: json, jq

I have this bit of json:

```
    [{
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Ice",
        "categories": [{
            "products": [{
                    "id": "66642",
                    "display_name": "Ice A"
                },
                {
                    "id": "62466",
                    "display_name": "Ice B"
                },
                {
                    "id": "62466",
                    "display_name": "Ice B duplicate"
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 97,
        "name": "Cakes",
        "categories": [{
            "products": [{
                    "id": "14518",
                    "display_name": "Cake 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "14105",
                    "display_name": "Cake 2"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

I'm using jq 1.6 and I'm trying to get this output:

```
[{
  "id": "62466",
  "name": "Ice B",
  "category": "Ice"
},
{
  "id": "66642",
  "name": "Ice A",
  "category": "Ice"
},
{
  "id": "14105",
  "name": "Cake 2",
  "category": "Cakes"
},
{
  "id": "14518",
  "name": "Cake 1",
  "category": "Cakes"
}]
```

I've tried with this code:

```
.[].name as $x | map(.categories[].products[]) | unique_by(.id) | .[] | 
[{
    id: .id,
    name: .display_name,
    category: $x
}]
```

But I get this output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "14105",
    "name": "Cake 2",
    "category": "Ice"
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": "14518",
    "name": "Cake 1",
    "category": "Ice"
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": "62466",
    "name": "Ice B",
    "category": "Ice"
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": "66642",
    "name": "Ice A",
    "category": "Ice"
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": "14105",
    "name": "Cake 2",
    "category": "Cakes"
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": "14518",
    "name": "Cake 1",
    "category": "Cakes"
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": "62466",
    "name": "Ice B",
    "category": "Cakes"
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": "66642",
    "name": "Ice A",
    "category": "Cakes"
  }
]
```

I looks like as there are two names

```
Ice
Cakes
```

It's multiplying the output by two , one for each name instead of just returning the 4 products and I can't get the result into and array of objects. Here is a reproducible code in [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/ELjP4cjXmYQ). Because there are some duplicate records, ie: products that have more than one category I need them to be unique. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Assigning the category name in a variable and then transforming each product with unique id:

```
map(
    .name as $category
    | .categories[].products
    | unique_by(.id)
    | .[]
    | { id, name: .display_name, $category }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This map produces the 4 unique items.

```bash
jq 'map(
  (.categories[].products | unique_by(.id)[] | {id, name: .display_name})
  + {category: .name}
)'
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "62466",
    "name": "Ice B",
    "category": "Ice"
  },
  {
    "id": "66642",
    "name": "Ice A",
    "category": "Ice"
  },
  {
    "id": "14105",
    "name": "Cake 2",
    "category": "Cakes"
  },
  {
    "id": "14518",
    "name": "Cake 1",
    "category": "Cakes"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YC4G5nt5lIB)

Comment: Because there are some duplicate records, ie: products that have more than one category. But not in the little sample I posted. About the ordering it doesn't matter

Comment: I've the updated the JSON code

Comment: So just to comment on your previous, simplified, version ´map((.categories[].products[] | {id, name: .display_name}) + {category: .name})´.

For what I understand you are using ´+ {category: .name}´  as a $variable

Comment: @PerseP I'm using it with the same effect. Instead of storing the category in a variable before traversal and reading it afterwards, I just pull the value directly when needed. The context is kept because of the parentheses around the other parts.

Comment: @PerseP Also (and especially wrt variable vs context), the previous version is identical to the current one with the only exception that `| unique_by(.id)` was missing in the previous one (as were duplicate values in your previous sample).

Comment: Yes I was using it to comment because it's shorter

Comment: I was thinking that one of the drawbacks of this solution is that you are not really flexible as to where the `{category: .name}` goes as with the `.name as $category` you can put `$category ` wherever you want in the object more easily

Comment: @PerseP Technically, you can with this as well (if it's not at the beginning or the end you have to split up the other part), but I admit it's ugly. On the other hand, the order of keys in an object based on the order of adding up its parts is just a side-effect of jq. JSON does not support a specific key order, and other JSON processors (or a future version of jq) might just disregard the ordering you can obtain here.